# How to change customer price group on customer account update?

Tags: magento2, customer, price, group, account

I have a custom customer attribute (registrationcode), on the registration form when the customer gives a code it automatically set the good group price.

How to update the group price when the customer gives a code when it updates the attribute on this account page?

Comment: Please define your Magento Version.

Comment: magento version 2.3.4